# Java super() inheritance

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

A short summary of the question: I have a parent class which is extended by a child class.

```
     public class Parent{

        public Parent(){
          //constructor logic
        }
     }
```

This child class calls the Parent's constructor using super:

```
     public class Child extends Parent{

         public Child(){
            super();
         }
     }
```

I was wondering if I were to extend the Child class if I could call the super() method in the Grandchild class' constructor:

```
    public class Grandchild extends Child{

         public Grandchild(){
            super();
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

super() is calling constructor one level up on the inheritance and it is called implicitly, if there is a no-arg constructor.

Objects are initialized from the top level of inheritance, in your case it is Object > Parent > Child > Grandchild.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html):

```
If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler
automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass. If the super 
class does not have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error. Object does 
have such a constructor, so if Object is the only superclass, there is no problem.
```

Answer (score 6):

That would call the `Child` class constructor, which in turn will call the `Parent` class constructor.