# can please explain the piece of code in j2me program ..!

Tags: java, java-me

```
public class hello extends MIDlet
{
private Form form;
private Display display;
public hello()
{
// what does this super keyword foes in this program
super();    
}
```

what does the super keyword does in thos program...?

Comment: please format your question

Comment: Short answer: no, we can not.

Comment: its calling the constructor of the MIDlet, but note this will be done also without the super(); call.... so it does nothing really in this case...

Comment: See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102034/java-super-inheritance

Answer (score 2):

super refers to the constructor of the super class. It is calling the constructor of MIDlet.